# Scrolling and disappearing elements

Tags: javascript, css

I was checking out some sites today and came across a new CSS or JS trick that I hadn't seen before but I really liked. I couldn't figure out how it was done or where I could learn more about it. Here is [a link](http://iconbench.com/) to the site where I saw the effect. It happens when you click on the "sign in" button at the top. What language is used to write that code and where can I learn about it?

Comment: Screenshots and code will get you much farther than that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have used simple jquery & css functions to implement this one.

This is theirs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var toggleLogin = 1;
$(".toggleLogin").click(function () {
    if (toggleLogin == 1) {
        toggleLogin = 0;
        $("#login").animate({ top: 0 });
        $("#IconBenchUsername").focus();
    } else {
        toggleLogin = 1;
        $("#login").animate({ top: -43 });
    }
    $("#invisLoginArea").slideToggle();
});
});
```

Comment: I would also fire that animate on delay so as to prevent the event queuing up and firing multiple times, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490536/animate-queue-simulation-for-older-jquery-verions-drupal-conflict/13556380#13556380)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Javascript or CSS3, it's a simple animation effect. By the way, CSS3 is much easier for you I think. You can search animation and transform in Google for more details.